# Inconsistent Output Voltage in DC-DC Buck Converter

Tags: power, buck, switching, converter

I'm trying to implement the following tps54302 DC-DC buck converter, for a 5V 3A output:

[image: Buck Reference Design]

All resistor values 1% tolerance, capacitors 5% tolerance, inductor 20% tolerance.

I'm testing with a bench top power supply at 12V and under a small load (~15 Ohm) output. I cannot figure out why the output voltage repeatedly drops from 5V to ~0.4V for extended periods of time (~40ms).
[image]
When testing smaller output currents (larger resistors), the frequency and duration of these voltage drops seemed to decrease.

For reference, the PCB Layout and FB pin. Note that the green traces underneath the regulator are currently not connected to anything.
[image]
[image]

As a final note, the application I am designing for is back powering a raspberry pi through its GPIO pins. When trying this, the raspberry pi begins to boot, then when the voltage drops (seemingly when current draw increases) it turns off and begins its boot again.

Here are scope shots of input voltage, switch node, and shunt resistor in series with the inductor (~1.5 ohm) respectively. 
[image: Vin]
[image: Switch node]
[image: Shunt resistor]

Comment: Looks like the part is going into current limit.

Comment: Could you specify? Should be about 0.33A going through the inductor, well within the regulator's specifications.

Comment: Thermal limit? Is the chip getting warm?

Comment: Warm to the touch but nowhere near its operating limit (125C).

Comment: It does look like it's shut down too long to be the hiccup current limit, so maybe it is the thermal limit.  The thermal hiccup may keep the package temperature only warm to the touch because of the duty cycle, but the die may be thermal cycling.  Can you get a scope shot of the inductor current and the switch node?

Comment: What's the rated saturation current (not maximum current) of the inductor?

Comment: @JohnD Will try to upload the switch node soon. Don't have a current probe unfortunately, however Vout in the datasheet's schematic is connected to just the 15 ohm resistor to ground. So I would expect the inductor current to be very close to Vout/15 based on the circuit.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, inductor p/n is [7447714100](https://katalog.we-online.de/pbs/datasheet/7447714100.pdf) from Wurth Electronics, rated for 4.3A, 5A saturation.

Comment: Peak inductor current should be ballpark 800mA so that seems fine. Are you sure the 22uF isn’t way less (or missing)? Maybe check the cap in the feedback path too.

Comment: Also maybe check the input voltage to be sure it's not dipping.

Comment: I see R1 to R5 in the schematic but no mention of them in the layout. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @JohnD checked and added inductor current, switch node, and input voltage. Also a thought: in the datasheet, thermal shutdown is 32768 cycles (~82ms @400kHz) and overcurrent shutdown is 16384 cycles (~41ms). Does this lend credit to the overcurrent idea?

Comment: @Andyaka the schematic linked is from the TI datasheet, while the pcb layout is from my project files, hence the difference in enumeration for the passive components. Apologies for the confusion, but the connections are all the same as the provided schematic.

Comment: It does look like it could be overcurrent.  Maybe something on the output is shorted or damaged?  With everything powered off what's the resistance between the output and ground measured with an ohm meter?  Can you isolate the load from the converter by lifting components or cutting traces?  You could try powering the output with a current limited lab supply to see what happens as well.

Comment: @JohnD Disconnected the load, put 5V between output and ground from a bench top power supply and measured 0A flowing from the power supply.

Comment: In the process I tried powering the buck converter with 12V and no load and it continuously drew 90mA. The package also got quite hot - however 5V was held at the output.

Comment: That's not normal, sounds like you have a damaged part.